# MonoDevelop Addon-ons like Eclipse

Tags: monodevelop

Are there refactoring and other addons for MonoDevelop like there are for Eclipse and Visual Studio, there does not appear to be an ecosystem of addons to help development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, there aren't third party refactoring add-ins for MonoDevelop. However, the IDE itself includes many refactoring operations and coding helpers, so maybe you'll find what you need without having to use an add-in.